# CrawlSpider / Scrapy - CLOSESPIDER settings are not working

Tags: python, scrapy, timeout, limit

I created a `CrawlSpider` that should follow all "internal" links up to a certain number of items / pages / time.

I am using `multiprocessing.Pool` to process a few pages at the same time (e.g. 6 workers).

I do call the `CrawlSpider` with the `os.system`comand from a separate python script:

```
import os
...

cmd = "scrapy crawl FullPageCrawler -t jsonlines -o "{0}" -a URL={1} -s DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE=0 -s CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT=180 -s CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT=150 -s CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT=100 -s DEPTH_LIMIT=5 -s DEPTH_PRIORITY=0 --nolog'.format(OUTPUT_FILE, url.strip())"
os.system(cmd)
```

It works pretty well for some of my pages but for specific pages the `crawler` is not following any of my set settings.

I tried to define the following (with what I think it does): 
`CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT`: The number of total pages he will follow? 
`CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT`: Not sure about this one. What is the difference to PAGECOUNT? 
`CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT`: Maximum time a crawler should be working.

Right now I face an example that has already crawled more than 4000 pages (or items?!) and is up for more than 1 hour.

Do I run into this because I defined everything at the same time?
Do I also need to define the same settings in the `settings.py`?
Can one of them be enough for me? (e.g. maximum uptime = 10minutes)

I tried using `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.system` because it has a `wait` function but this was not working as expected as well.

After all using `os.system` is the most stable thing I tried and I want to stick with it. Only problem is `scrapy`

I tried searching for an answer on SO but couldn´t find any help!

EDIT:
The above example ended up with 16.009 **scraped** subpages and over 333 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After keep on searching for an answer I came up with the following solution.

Within my `CrawlSpider` I defined a maximum number of pages (`self.max_cnt`) that the **scraper** should stop at and a counter that is checked (`self.max_counter`) and increased for each page my **scraper** visited.

If the number of maximum pages is exceeded then the spider will be closed by raising `scrapy.exception.CloseSpider`.

```
class FullPageSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "FullPageCrawler"
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback="parse_all", follow=True),)

    def __init__(self, URL=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FullPageSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = [URL]
        self.allowed_domains = ['{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=urlparse(URL))]
        self.max_cnt = 250
        self.max_counter = 0

    def parse_all(self, response):
        if self.max_counter < self.max_cnt:
                self.max_cnt += 1
                
                ...

        else:
            from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
            raise CloseSpider('Exceeded the number of maximum pages!')
```

This works fine for me now but I would still be interested in the reason why the crawler settings are not working as expected.

Comment: fyi it's __scraper__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraping__) not scrapper